# Activity class object is valid after onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-activity

1) What is going on with activity (Preference activity in particular case) life cycle point of view, 
when Activity is destroyed, but I'm calling it's public method from other class, which has "pointer" to this activity?

2) **Why pointer is valid**, if Activity class is destroyed after **onDestroy()**.
Is it safe to use such pointers or pointer is working, just while memory is not cleaned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm no memory management expert.

> Why pointer is valid, if Activity class is destroyed after onDestroy()

You have the pointer, that's why object is prevented from being destroyed by GC. So by keeping reference to an object which is a subject to garbage collection, you're creating a **memory leak**.

The rule of thumb is to never create a references, which can keep Activity instance from being garbage-collected. Moreover, keeping a reference to an Activity is against inter-component communication model. Instead, use `Intents` or Application-level objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Is it written somewhere in a trusted web pages(android docs/ I/O presentations / Google developers blogs) about such  rule (never create references to Activity)?
Intents are not always perfect, to substitute direct method calls.

Comment: @Denis yes, sometimes you need to pass complex data or notify other Activity about event. But that's the price for modular and self-contained nature of Activity. But believe me, when you follow guidelines for some time, you'll see that all these contstraints help you build a better app.